# PrintedPdfDocument vs PdfDocument

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-generation

Could not find much difference in the Doc

What is the difference between them ? and when one should prefer one over other ?

For Android PDF Generation

Answer (score 1):

`PrintedPdfDocument` It is an auxiliary class.

For example, it takes the value of `printAttributes`.

**Sample UseCase**

```
val printAttributes = PrintAttributes.Builder()
            .setColorMode(PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_COLOR)
            .setMediaSize(pageSize.pageType)
            .setResolution(PrintAttributes.Resolution("res1", "300_DPI", 300, 300))
            .setMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS)
            .build()

        doc = PrintedPdfDocument(context, printAttributes)
```

As you can see, you can make **customizations**.

The most important point

```
public class PrintedPdfDocument extends PdfDocument
```

It is **extended** from the PdfDocument class.

If you are going to do customization, I recommend using `PrintedPdfDocument` .